# Main method entry point with string argument gives "does not contain ... suitable ... entry point" error

Tags: c#, syntax

Why does the code block below give a compile error of "does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point"?

```
namespace MyConApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string args) 
        {
            string tmpString; 
            tmpString = args;
            Console.WriteLine("Hello" + tmpString);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/) to understand  `Main` method signature options.

Answer (score 6):

In the code you provide the problem is that the 'Main' entry point is expecting a array of strings passed from system when the program is invoked (this array can be null, has no elements)

to correct change

```
static void Main(string args)
```

to

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

You could get the same error if you declared your 'Main' of any type other than 'void' or 'int'

so the signature of the 'Main' method has always to be

```
static // ie not dynamic, reference to method must exist
public // ie be accessible from the framework invoker
Main   // is the name that the framework invoker will call

string[] <aName> // can be ommited discarding CLI parameters
* is the command line parameters space break(ed)
```

From MS
(...)
The Main method can use arguments, 
in which case, it takes one of the following forms:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
static void Main(string[] args)
```

Answer (score 5):

Because the argument is String and not a String Array as expected

Answer (score 4):

The only valid signatures for `Main` method are :

```
static void Main()
```

and

```
static void Main(string[])
```

---

`static void Main(string)` is not a valid signature for `Main` method.

Comment: Actually return type may also be int instead of void.

Answer (score 2):

The signature of the main method must be `main(String[])`, not `main(String)`.