# C# Basic Comprehension Questions

Tags: c#

I am ashamed that this is a most basic task to accomplish in C# and I can't seem to figure it out. Yeah, I can compile it and make it run, but I want to dissect it and be understand it, word for word.

```
using System;  *//"include standard System classes"*
namespace DataTypeApplication  *//"Create new classes within DataTypeApp..."*
{
   class Program  *//"Name this class "Program""*
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)  *//Declares the main function of this class?*
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Size of int: {0}", sizeof(int));  *//Print string using sizeof(int)*
          Console.ReadLine();  *//Irrelevant*
      }
   }
}
```

I am confused as to why this will run. Program has been created but not called. And also, this outputs 4 for the int, but where the heck does the 4 come from?

I'd appreciate any help understanding this, although, maybe C# just isn't for me. -_-

Comment: `int` is `In32` which means 32 bit which is 4 byte.

Comment: `sizeof(int)` returns the size of the `int` type which is 4 bytes. And that is inserted for the `{0}` placeholder in the string. The `ReadLine` asks for user input and is a way to keep the program alive until you read the whole output. The rest is correct.

Comment: Look in the project properties and you will see where "Program.Main" is the "entry point"

Comment: Regarding `Main`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069606/entry-point-error-for-mainstring-args

Comment: Note that `using System;` does not really _include_ classes, it just allows you to type `Console` while you're actually referring to `System.Console`. To include additional classes you'd have to add a reference to their assemblies in your project.

Answer (score 4):

> Program has been created but not called

`Program.Main` is your program's entry point, which is baked into the metadata of you .exe file. You can see the entry point under your project settings in Visual Studio, or if you use ILDASM to de-compose your file you'll see it in the header section.

> And also, this outputs 4 for the int, but where the heck does the 4
>   come from

The [`sizeof` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx) will yield the size in bytes of the unmanaged type. The `int` keyword is an alias for `Int32`, which is a 4 byte representative of an integral type.

Answer (score 2):

Every program has its entry point - usually this entry called Main function in your case:

```
void Main(string[] args)
```

`sizeof(int)` returns you `4` since this is the size of int type on your machine - `4` bytes.

Comment: Mind that in C#, `int` is not machine specific, but always 32 bits, thus 4 bytes. In C++, it's another story.